# where to report wrong hash sum in an ubuntu update failure?

Tags: md5sum, cairo-dock

the firefox update fails because the cairo-dock package and five other cairo-dock-packages have an incorrect hash sum and thus cannot be downloaded. I cannot find any way to report such a problem since "ubuntu-bug cairo-dock" tells me that such a package does not exist. Very frustrating.

Bernhard

Comment: Could you post the output of `apt-cache policy cairo-dock`? Try re-downloading the package by clearing your cache (`apt-get clean`) followed by an refresh (`apt-get update`) and finally the upgrade (`apt-get upgrade`)

Comment: this is after apt-get clean/apt-get update/apt-get upgrade : apt-cache policy cairo-dock
cairo-dock:
  Installiert: 2.3.0~2-2ubuntu1~natty
  Kandidat:    2.3.0~3-1ubuntu0~natty
  Versionstabelle:
     2.3.0~3-1ubuntu0~natty 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-team/ppa/ubuntu/ natty/main i386 Packages
 *** 2.3.0~2-2ubuntu1~natty 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.3.0~1-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://mirror.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pub/linux/distributions/ubuntu/ natty/universe i386 Packages

Comment: problem gone! questions remains where to report? What should I expect when I type "ubuntu-bug cairo-dock"?

Comment: Probably not a problem with the package, but an interrupted update or a temporary network problem caused the hash mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

The package **cairo-dock** is a meta package for **[cairo-dock-core](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/cairo-dock-core)** and for **cairo-dock-pulg-ins**. You may be able to file an ubuntu bug against cairo-dock-core.

A valuable source for help and additional information is the well maintained upstream web-site for **[Glx-Dock](http://www.glx-dock.org/index.php)**. They even have an active forum to discuss features and bugs.